# How do I use Mandrill to send a simple email to my Parse powered apps administrator in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, parse-platform, mandrill

I can't find any clear examples on how to get started.

My app uses the parse framework and I've registered a Mandrill account.

The instructions aren't clear to be honest.

Would appreciate some help.

I've gone on both parse and mandrills websites and looked at the getting started docs but it still makes little sense to me.

Do I create a JSON file in my app?

Does it need to be in a particular folder?

Please help me get started.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sending mail using mandrill when using parse.com, it should be done using parse.com cloud functions

[starting with parse.com cloud functions](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide)
[mandrill starting guide](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_modules_guide#mandrill)

Recently i worked with integration of mailgun with parse.com

Comment: Perfect and very easy. Now up and running.